# NAudio looking for a way to read from a Stream when changing pitch instead of a File

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, naudio

I am using the Naudio lib in my project and I've used it already to combine MP3 files and use them.
I combined them using Mp3FileReader(Stream), so it is possible to read from a stream with this object but when I try to change the audio pitch and follow their tutorial this is how it goes:

```
    using (var reader = new MediaFoundationReader(inPath)) //only reads from file
{
    var pitch = new SmbPitchShiftingSampleProvider(reader.ToSampleProvider());
    using(var device = new WaveOutEvent())
    {
        pitch.PitchFactor = (float)upOneTone; // or downOneTone
        // just playing the first 10 seconds of the file
        device.Init(pitch.Take(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)));
        device.Play();
        while(device.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }
}
```

now my problem is that MediaFoundationReader only reads from file, is there another way to load from a stream and change the pitch/ frequency.

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this code will help you:
This function receive a Stream instead a file path.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using NAudio.Wave;
using NAudio.Wave.SampleProviders;
namespace Test
{
    public class HelpOnStackOverFlow
    {
        public static void PlayShift(Stream stream)
        {
            var fr = new Mp3FileReader(stream);

            fr.ToSampleProvider();
            var pitch = new SmbPitchShiftingSampleProvider(fr.ToSampleProvider());

            var rates = new float[] { 1.0594630943593f, 1.12246204830937f, 1.18920711500272f, 1.25992104989487f };

            foreach (var rate in rates)
            {

                var device = new WaveOutEvent();
                pitch.PitchFactor = rate;
                device.Init(pitch.Take(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));
                device.Play();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, if possible you should [edit] your answer to include a short explanation of *how* this code block answers the question. This helps to provide context and makes your answer much more useful for future readers.